# Remove horizontal space in bmatrix

Tags: latex, alignment

I would like to remove the right spacing between the letter and the bracket

i created this equation

```
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{\mathbf{f}} \nonumber&\\ \mathrm{\mathbf{f}}^*&
\end{bmatrix} 
\sim \mathcal{N}\left(
\textbf{0},
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
K & K_*^\top \nonumber\\
K_* & K_{**} 
\end{array}\right]\right). \nonumber\\[7pt]\nonumber
\end{align}
```

Would like to remove the spacing on the right

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com would be better suited for this question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mleftright`](//ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) to have better spacing between brackets. Alternatively, you can use a forced negative space `\!` to bring things closer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathrm{\mathbf{f}} \\
    \mathrm{\mathbf{f}}^\star
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \sim \mathcal{N} \mleft(
    \mathbf{0},
    \begin{bmatrix}
      K & K_\star^\top \\
      K_\star & K_{\star\star} 
    \end{bmatrix}\mright)
\]

\end{document}
```